# How to save large datasets to a checkpoint-file in MATLAB when training a neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, save, bigdata, checkpointing

When training a neural network with large datasets (and few features) in MATLAB, the tr structure will grow above 2 GB making the automatic checkpoint-saving feature unusable. MATLAB throws the following error:

```
Warning: Variable 'checkpoint' was not saved. For variables larger than 2GB use MAT-file version 7.3 or later.
```

Is there any workaround. This is very unfortunate as checkpoint-files can be the most useful for large datasets.

Comment: You can change the default version to v7.3. See this [link](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html) for more information.

Comment: @m7913d Thanks. It appears to be possible. However, I am looking for a solution that does not depend on making changes to the MATLAB folder/alter MATLABs default behavior.

Comment: It's up to you, but I think v7.3 is a better default if you are working with large data files.

Comment: @m7913d I totally agree. But sometimes I will be in a position where I cannot make changes like these on the system; that's why I was looking for a "permanent" solution.